# MySQL WorkBench Unicode hell under Windows(R)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm tired, guys... Since 6.2.5 the WB does not support unicode in its configuration.

Let's compare:

6.2.5:
Workplace restores just fine. Cyrillic in paths and names is OK.
[image: Filenames are OK]

8.0.2:
Same workplace isn't restorable: any Cyrillic in path/names turns into unreadable hieroglyphs
[image: filenames are thrashed]

Almost 2yo ago I already filed the [bugreport](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87520). But no reaction, no corrections, no attention...

So, please suggest me how to enable normal unicode support, or suggest me another functionally close tool. Fonts aren't problem: as you can see on second screensho, the 2-byte UTF8 chars were converted to 2-char representations (note repeating "D"-like symbol)

Comment: Have you tried the latest WB release (8.0.15 at this time of writing)? I'll take care to raise prio for your bug report.

Comment: No. At the time of writing only 8.0.2 was available. But you may check .15 by yourself - create new script and save it with non-latin characters in the name. Then try to restore this workspace...

Comment: And who changed "Unicode hell" to "Unicode shell:?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow isn’t Oracle’s bug tracker.

Comment: @MikeLischke tried 8.0.15. All the same: I can open and save files with Cyrillics in the names, but workplace can't be restored then (see attachments in bugreport)